# Truck Arrival at a specific dock via Database

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to retrieve the truck arrivals via database at specific docks. So for example at 5 am my truck should arrive and start loading at dock XY.The next truck should load at dock YZ. I have 10 gates. How can I connect the database with the docks? I have a complete network so the pallets of the pallet rack storages were send to the dock storages where the trucks begin loading similar to the example model "distribution center". Thank you for helping!

Comment: How are you modelling your trucks? Agents, resources, transporters? Share some screenshots and also: what have you tried already? Please help us help you :-) (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Same modelling like in the example model distribution center. Trucks are an agent, resources forklifts, the docks are also a resource pool "dockloading". I tried to create a process flow named loading process for every single dock with the different nodes but the trucks arrives only on one dock to the specified time though.

Comment: each dock has an id, put the id in the database, and send the trucks to the dock with that id.

Comment: where can I get the id for the docks? or how can I create a id for a dock?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SOF. Just a tip: "Same modelling like in the example model distribution center." is not helpful. We are happy to help but very short on time :-) Make our lives easy by providing the info (screenshots, explanations...). Hope that makes sense. Treat us as helpful, but  VERY busy colleagues ;-)

Comment: @Felipe where can I get the id for the docks? or how can I create a id for a dock?

Comment: there is a getId() function... but what you want to do I think is to have a parameter called id, and have the docks defined in the database and create them with that parameter

Comment: but when I have a parameter called id, which ids should I put in my database ? I have an agent called dock  with my different docks. The problem is that I don't know how to give the different docks an ID

Comment: So the only problem I have is to get a ID respectively to find the IDs of the different docks which I can write into my database after I create the parameter id for an agent. So the population of the agent dock named loadDocks.